# Blank space in Minipage

Tags: minipage

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=0.00cm, height=0.00cm, left=0.80in, right=0.80in, top=0.80in, bottom=0.80in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \large
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
In $\triangle{ABC}$ $\angle B = 90^{\circ}$,\\
By using Pythagoras Theorem,
\begin{align*}
AC^2&=AB^2+BC^2& \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0:0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0:5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(90:4){C}



\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.6mm](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}

\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](B,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)


\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap,rotate=-38.5,xshift=-15mm,yshift=0mm](A,C){Hypotenuse}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=0,xshift=0.3mm,yshift=-0.7mm](A,B){Adjacent Side}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=90,xshift=15.3mm,yshift=3.8mm](B,C){Opposite Side}


%% here use the correct order. For example, BCA is inner angle and ACB is outer angle
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0cm,color=red,mark=](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](C,A,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Question: In my work the main issue is there is a some blank space in the left side of page, i mean whatever i written in the left side it is creating some blank space which is indicated by a red symbol. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry sir i was facing some trouble while inserting image of my work

Comment: you have specified two minipages each .5\textwidth wise to be postioned with 2cm of space plus a normal word space between them. What do you want to happen in this case? they clearly will not fit side by side on the same line.

Comment: Oh no, that was the issue. i am absolutely sorry

Comment: reason behind my 2cm space that i was looking for some distance between my minipages

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the hspace in itself but simple arithmetic suggests that .5\textwidth+.5\textwidth+2cm+.3em is more than \textwidth:-) use .4\textwidth and use \hfill for the space then it will expand to fill the .2\textwidth gap.

Comment: @snehal - If you want the material in the first `minipage` to be top-aligned, at the position specifier `[b]`, i.e, write `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}`.

Comment: they are by default using `[c]` position so they are aligned so that their vertical middles are on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you (a) make the `minipage` environments slightly less wide, say, `0.45\textwidth` instead of `0.5\textwidth`; (b) insert `\hspace{\fill}` between them; and (c) insert a `\flushright` instruction at the start of the right-hand `minipage`. (By default, items in `minipage` are fully-justified, i.e., they start out at the left-hand edge.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\large
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
In $\triangle{ABC}$ $\angle B = 90^{\circ}$,\\
By using Pythagoras Theorem,
\begin{align*}
AC^2&=AB^2+BC^2& \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\flushright
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0:0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0:5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(90:4){C}

\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.6mm](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}

\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](B,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)

\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap,rotate=-38.5,xshift=-15mm,yshift=0mm](A,C){Hypotenuse}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=0,xshift=0.3mm,yshift=-0.7mm](A,B){Adjacent Side}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=90,xshift=15.3mm,yshift=3.8mm](B,C){Opposite Side}

%% here use the correct order. For example, BCA is inner angle and ACB is outer angle
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0cm,color=red,mark=](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](C,A,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for the edit!